# Effect of changing resolution on battery

Tags: battery-life, screen-resolution

There are various ways to change the resolution on Android devices, and I was wondering: Does it have any noticable effect on battery life? And has anybody ever tried doing some proper measurements?

Comment: Have you tried experimenting it (research) or perhaps searching about it? It should lead you to some point I suppose. What is it?

Comment: @Firelord I indeed tried searching for it with very little luck. Why do you think I ended up here with the question ;-) And no, I have not started doing any research myself, because that would mean I couldn't use my phone for at least a couple of days whilst I run each test at a different resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the reduction in power consumption will not be significant, but you can easily test this yourself using free software like [Trepn Profiler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quicinc.trepn&hl=en). Disclosure: I am part of the team that makes this software. Make sure to follow these [best practices](http://mostly-tech.com/2015/05/28/how-to-measure-the-power-consumption-of-your-mobile-app-using-free-software/), if you want to get the most accurate results.

Another method to measure power consumption is using Monsoon Power Monitor hardware. I forced the screen resolution to 240 dpi using this adb command:

```
adb shell wm density DPI && adb reboot
```

Then I measured the power consumption idle and under a load at 240 dpi using the Monsoon Power Monitor. I used the Adreno Test app to load my device. Next I remeasured at the 560 dpi, which is the native resolution of my Nexus 6. At 240 dpi, icons and text appear much smaller on the screen.

Here are the results:

**Idle power consumption**

> 240 dpi: 514 mW
>
> 560 dpi: 522 mW

**Power consumption under load**

> 240 dpi: 3155 mW
>
> 560 dpi: 3287 mW

**Bottom line:** My simple test showed there is almost no benefit to reducing the resolution of your screen via software.